# Graph library for mono?

Tags: c#, graph, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm building a program and I'm going to need to do some basic graph problems: find strongly connected components, find shortest traversal, etc. I know that the quckgraph library works with .net but doesn't port to mono. Does anyone know the best way to get around this, or if there's another library out there I could use?

Comment: Is quickgraph opensource or closed source?

Comment: Waht is the problem with quickgraph.  It should be ok in Mono as it's fully managed.

Comment: The OP mentions Unity3D. They run a 'mostly compatible' old version of mono. It would be compatible with .net 3.5, but not really. I haven't been able to find an up-to-date reference of what is- and what isn't supported yet. Nor a reason why they don't want to update to new mono versions.

Answer (score 1):

QuickGraph once worked fine with Mono for me. I just downloaded the newest library, referenced it in project, built simple example and still works like a charm. What problem do you have with it in mono?

Comment: You use QuickGraph under Linux or Mac OSX with Mono? Did you build QuickGraph under Mono? I can't get it to build.

Answer (score 1):

[Satsuma](http://satsumagraph.sourceforge.net) is much simpler than QuickGraph and should work for you, though there are no releases yet and you will need to check it out from Git.